# Overriding method in C++

Tags: c++, overriding

I am trying to override function `add()` in the inherited class NumericInput. But when I call `add()` on a NumericInput object the `add()` function in the base class is called. Why is this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TextInput
{
public:
    std::string cur;
    void add(char c) 
   {
        cur += c;
        std::cout<<"input is: "<<c<<'\n';
   }

   std::string getValue() {return cur;}
};

class NumericInput : public TextInput 
{
   public:
   void add(char c) 
   {
    if(c>=48 && c <= 57)
    {
        std::cout<<"input is a digit: "<< c <<'\n';
        cur += c;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"input is not digit"<<'\n';}
    }
};

int main()
{
    TextInput* input = new NumericInput();
    input->add('1');
    input->add('a');
    input->add('0');
    std::cout << input->getValue();
}
```

Comment: Make it `virtual`.

Comment: Calling a method of a pointer to base class will always call the base class member function unless said function is virtual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, make it `virtual`.  It is also good practice to mark the overriding function with `override`.  That way you will get a compiler error when there is no function to override (usually because of a typo in the name).

Also any class with virtual functions should have a virtual destructor so that it can be deleted via a pointer.  Don't forget to to delete the pointer as well!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TextInput
{
public:
    std::string cur;

    virtual ~TextInput() = default;

    virtual void add(char c)
    {
        cur += c;
        std::cout<<"input is: "<<c<<'\n';
    }

    std::string getValue() {return cur;}
};

class NumericInput : public TextInput 
{
public:
    virtual void add(char c) override
    {
        if(c>=48 && c <= 57)
        {
            std::cout<<"input is a digit: "<< c <<'\n';
            cur += c;
        }
        else
        {std::cout<<"input is not digit"<<'\n';}
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    TextInput* input = new NumericInput();
    input->add('1');
    input->add('a');
    input->add('0');
    std::cout << input->getValue() << '\n';
    delete input;
}
#endif
```

---

This is also a good place to apply the **non-virtual interface** idiom.  The base class has a member function `add` which is not virtual and takes care of add the character to the string `cur`.  It does so if `do_add` reports that the character should be added.  The function `do_add` is virtual and, most importantly, private.  This ensures encapsulation and makes the class portable.  See Item 35 “Consider alternatives to virtual functions” in *Effective C++* by Scott Meyers.

Also, use a `std::unique_ptr` to manage the memory of your class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class TextInput
{
    std::string cur;

    virtual bool do_add(char c)
    {
        std::cout<<"input is: "<<c<<'\n';
        return true;
    }

public:
    virtual ~TextInput() = default;

    void add(char c)
    {
        if ( do_add(c) )
            cur += c;
    }

    std::string getValue()
    {
        return cur;
    }
};

class NumericInput : public TextInput 
{
    virtual bool do_add(char c) override
    {
        if ( c>=48 && c <= 57 )
        {
            std::cout<<"input is a digit: "<< c <<'\n';
            return true;
        }

        std::cout<<"input is not digit"<<'\n';
        return false;
    }
};

#ifndef RunTests
int main()
{
    auto input = std::unique_ptr<TextInput>{new NumericInput()};
    input->add('1');
    input->add('a');
    input->add('0');
    std::cout << input->getValue() << '\n';
}
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answers. Can you explain the use of <TextInput>{new NumericInput()}? 
    std::unique_ptr<TextInput>{new NumericInput()}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using :

```
bool my_isdigit(char ch)
{
    return std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));
}
```

in order to verify that your char is digit or not